# What is this seed error trying to tell me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, terminal

I am making a RoR app that has to do with comic books and I keep getting this error after I use the rails db:seed command:

```
rails aborted!

SyntaxError: 

/Users/cggarcia171/Desktop/environment/ComicApp/db/seeds.rb:9: syntax 
error, unexpected tLABEL
ch1 = Character.create (alias:'Doctor Manhattan', name: 'Dr.
                          ^
/Users/cggarcia171/Desktop/environment/ComicApp/db/seeds.rb:9: syntax 
error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input 
ate (alias:'Doctor Manhattan', name: 'Dr. Jonathan 'Jon' Ost
                          ^
```

here is some of my code:

```
ch1 = Character.create 
(alias:'Doctor Manhattan', 
 name: "Dr. Jonathan 'Jon' Osterman", 
 image: 'Doctor_Manhattan.jpg', 
bio: 'He was originally 
Dr. Jonathan Osterman, a nuclear physicist who in 1959 was transformed 
into one of the most supreme beings of DC Comics, after initially being 
disintegrated in an Intrinsic Field Subtractor and later reconstructing 
himself. Following his reanimation, he was immediately pressed into 
service by the United States government, who gave him the name Doctor 
Manhattan, after the Manhattan Project. He is the only character in the 
story that possesses actual superpowers.')
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least three errors in your code:

1. Ruby actually is whitespace sensitive. `m (a, b)` and `m(a, b)` are entirely different things, the first is a syntax error (as Ruby tries to interpret the parentheses as grouping-parentheses but `(a, b)` is not a valid expression) whereas the second is a method call with two arguments.

   Remove the space between `Character.create` and `(`.
2. The value for `:name` contains nested single quotes that have not been properly escaped. You should have:

   ```
   name: 'Dr. Jonathan \'Jon\' Osterman'
   ```

   or double quotes, `%q{...}`, etc.
3. The `:bio` value doesn't have a closing quote.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Now i am getting an error saying "ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'alias' for Character." but I have "t.string :alias" in my .rb like the rest.

Comment: Has that migration been run? Is that column actually in the database? Does `db/schema.rb` mention your `alias` column? Perhaps you editing the migration after running it, if so then you'd need to undo that edit and add a new migration that adds the `alias` column.

Comment: When I run schema its telling me permission denied, But I have done "rails db:migrate"

Comment: Don't run `schema.rb`, look at it. Then look directly at the database. Then consider renaming it to something else (such as `aka`) to avoid any possible conflicts with the `alias` keyword.

Comment: I see what you mean. It does not say anything in that file other than the created at and updated at stuff. What should it look like?

Comment: Looks like you generated the migrations, ran them, then edited them to include your columns. Delete the old migrations for those three tables, add new ones that add the columns you need, then run the new migrations.

Answer (score -1):

The line `name: 'Dr. Jonathan 'Jon' Osterman'` is a broken string. Parser errors notoriously limp along after the actual error and then complain about something unrelated. Try `name: "Dr. Jonathan 'Jon' Osterman"`.

Then correctly format your seed, with lots of newlines, to help everyone see what's going on!